# Some info needed for Hadoop namenode

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop2

I am trying to understand Hadoop and I am referring to this book: `Hadoop: The definitive Guide"`.

I have some doubts in understanding the data which Namenode manages, please refer to the image below:

[image]

Based on this, I have the following questions:

Q1) What is the meaning of `filesystem namespace`?
Q2) what is the meaning of `filesystem tree`?
Q3) What is `meta-data`? Are `meta-data` and `namespace` two different things?
Q4) what is `namespace image`?
Q5) what is `edit logs`?

Can anyone please help me understanding this?
There are many terminologies involved and no clarity of term provided.

Answer (score 1):

Filesystem tree... */, /home, /tmp*, etc. The filesystem. HDFS is an abstraction layer over the physical disks it runs on.

Metadata.. *File xyz is located at /tmp and is 5KB large and is read-only*. Data stored that identifies any file - location, size, permissions, etc.

The namespace is the combination of these items.

---

An edit log is a transcript of actions performed against that image, to be fault tolerant and provide checkpoints at which data consistency is known. This mechanism has less overhead than comparing raw files within a distributed system.

The rest of the question is answered by [namespace image and edit log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26943161/namespace-image-and-edit-log)

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. In this diagram it says that fsimage and edit logs don't store the block location, and when datanode starts this information is constructed; how is this possible? Doesn't fsimage and edits have this information?

Comment: It does not store them persistently. Doesn't mean it doesn't store it at all. It sits in memory after the system starts and is constructed